# Community Moderator Election 2017/2018?

Tags: discussion, election, moderation

I've read up on the moderation process recently as I'd argue we only have 1 active moderator on Magento Stack Exchange (Marius). With Philip announcing that he'd be stepping down at Mage Titans Manchester 2017 and Ben doesn't seem to be as active as he used to be (I could be wrong on this, he may be doing things behind the scenes).

I can see Marius is doing a great job moderating but it seems a lot to do by himself. I'd be curious to know how a new election can be called to provide Marius some further support and to get some new moderators in place to aid in the management of Magento Stack Exchange.

Comment: I need help....

Comment: For real? Should think about doing an election/getting more mods on board maybe?

Comment: I don't have power over elections.

Comment: That's a shame - How is one called then?

Comment: I think @Marius is enough ;)

Comment: @Marius - According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99515/376535 you can reach out to Stack Exchange and ask for additional help that might prompt an election. Judging by the 11 upvotes this question has (At time of writing this comment) it might be a welcome sight to have a refreshened moderator team (Obviously including yourself ;))

Comment: I will talk tomorrow with the other 2 moderators and take a decision.

Comment: @Marius - Did you get a chance to catchup with the other 2 mods?

Comment: Yes. Things are still pending. Will keep you updated when something changes

Comment: I think we should just work @Marius into an early grave! j/k +1 for the question.

Comment: Working on it for next year (earliest timeframe possible)

Comment: Agree to @Eirik :P